# What is the name of derivation technique that uses finite/infinitesimal elements to derive formulas?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

This may be a strange question but I have not been able to find the name of this derivation method after hours of Googling. I have seen this technique all throughout my undergrad and grad years in physics but I have never heard of it being given an explicit name.

The technique in question is the one used in many introductory lectures in different areas of physics, in which someone draws a simplified small schematic of the system under consideration (for example, a section of a bent beam) and then starts deriving (for example) the equation for strain in an Euler-Bernoulli beam using small elements dx and basic physics and geometric relationships that relate this infitesimal element dx to the small angle dtheta and so on.

This section of the wikipedia page on Euler-Bernoulli beam bending theory illustrated what I am talking about, though I have seen it countless other times: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Bernoulli_beam_theory#Derivation_of_bending_moment_equation

My question is what is the name or class for this type of derivation technique? Does it even have a name? Googling things relation to infitesimal elements and finite elements did not yield what I wanted. It may or may not be more common in solid and fluid mechanics, as most of the examples I can think of seeing this in are from that field.

Comment: I don't think it has a specific name. It's just an application of differential calculus.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@knzhou is right.

You resort to Taylor's series about the point in the continuum. For example, the stress in $x$ direction at point $x$ is assumed $\sigma_{xx}$. Then at point $x+dx$, it would be $\sigma_{xx} + \frac{\partial \sigma_{xx}}{\partial x} dx$. So on.

Comment: I was afraid this might be the answer. Thank you anyway, at least I will not lose my mind trying to classify it.